# How to build connection with Angular.js and Node.js trough services?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, express

I've a simple Admin Panel which has form inside it. I'm trying to update this form's content trough Angular.js and Node.js connection. If i accomplish this: i will able to read form's data and render on the front page aswell.

This form reads data from: **"/json/form-data.json"**:

```
[{
  "name"    : "BigTitleLine1",
  "content" : "APP TITLE 1"
}, {
  "name"    : "BigTitleLine2",
  "content" : "APP TITLE 2"
}];
```

Angular **Service** gets data from that json file:

```
ServiceModule.factory('serviceFormData', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(rootPath("/json/form-data.json"), {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        }
    });
}]);
```

Angular **Controller** assigns data to model:

```
ctrl.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'serviceFormData',
    function($scope, $rootScope, serviceFormData) {

        $scope.model = {};
        serviceFormData.query(function(data) {
            $scope.model.formData = data;
        });
]);
```

I can show true data on the **HTML**, and save changes to the model:

```
<form>
      <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in model.formData">
          <label>- {{ item.name }}</label>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="item.content" required />
          <br />
      </div>
</form>
```

I've created a **Node.JS Express** server on my localhost. It can read and write files aswell.

```
var express = require('express'),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    app     = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// i can create "localhost:3000/test" page and show this json data over there
app.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({ some: "aq literal" });
});

// i can create "./json/test.json" file and write what i want.
fs.writeFile("./json/test.json", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

**I'm trying to write a json file which includes submited angular form's model.** Like this:

```
[{
  "name"    : "BigTitleLine1",
  "content" : "I've edited this json from my angular form which is on the client side."
}, {
  "name"    : "BigTitleLine2",
  "content" : "APP TITLE 2"
}];
```

How to build this connection between Angular.js and Node.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your factory to handle the new call to Node to update the file (or create a new factory):

```
ServiceModule.factory('serviceFormData', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/update', {}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

Then you should update the Angular controller with the update method:

```
var json = new serviceFormData.update($scope.item);

json.$update(function (response) {
    $scope.success = true;
}, function (response) {
    $scope.error = response;
});
```

And finally you should handle it by Node with a new route:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.put('/update', function (req, res) {
  var arr = []
    for (var index in req.body){
      arr.push(req.body[index])
    }
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);

    fs.writeFile("./json/test.json", jsonData, function(err) {
       if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
       }
       res.json({ success: true });
    });
});
```

I didn't test it but this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, **+1**. I've made the connection between angular and node.js but i can not write array data properly, [i've write another question for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271050/how-to-write-array-properly-on-node-js-express-with-fs) and i'm accepting your answers. Thanks again.

Comment: mmm if you console.log the data before you send it to Node, is it an array or an object?

Comment: its an array, just like its original.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271050/how-to-write-array-to-a-file-properly-on-node-js-express-with-fs

Comment: Please change the factory to: `update: { method: 'PUT', isArray: true }`

Comment: now it returns error: TypeError: json.$update is not a function

Comment: its solved, thanks for the effort mate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32271754/1428241

Comment: mate this method makes duplicated xhr calls twice /: