# How to write array to a file properly on node.js express with fs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to write an array as its on the file with node.js and [**i've used angular to achive this, you can inspect rest of the code from this question.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268250/how-to-build-connection-with-angular-js-and-node-js-trough-services)

When i send an array, file seems like this: [object Object],...

When i send my array inside `JSON.stringify(myArr)`, it writes properly on the file but data corrupts and converts as an a object.

**json**:

```
[{
  "name"    : "BigTitleLine1",
  "content" : "APP TITLE 1"
}, {
  "name"    : "BigTitleLine2",
  "content" : "APP TITLE 2"
}];
```

**node.js**:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
    app         = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.put('/update', function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);
  fs.writeFile("./json/test.json", req.body, function(err) {
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
  // this returns true data on console 
  // but it writes [object Object],[object Object] to the file

  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  console.log(jsonData);
  fs.writeFile("./json/test.json", jsonData, function(err) {
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
  // this way writes well but
  // it corrupts data and convert it to object:
  //{"0":{"name":"BigTitleLine1","content":"APP TITLE 1"},"1":{"name":...}}
});

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

I'm trying to write array as its on the file.

Comment: Stringifying your data should work. Have you tried removing the first `fs.writeFile`, i.e. only trying it with the second `fs.writeFile` (where you're stringifying your payload). Because now you have two async write statements that are creating a race condition that could potentially cause weird stuff to happen.

Comment: thanks for the help @danillouz but i didn't understand, can you write it down :?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
    app         = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.put('/update', function (req, res) {
  // convert object to array
  var arr = []
  for (var index in req.body){
    arr.push(req.body[index])
  }
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);
  console.log(jsonData);
  fs.writeFile("./json/test.json", jsonData, function(err) {
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Why do you require the loop?

Comment: hello mate, its because node.js thinks my model is an object but it should think as an array @danillouz

Comment: Oh I think I get it now, it's because of the angular model (array like object). Cool, thanks @BarlasApaydin, you have a badass website btw :)

Comment: hi mate, i've one more question, how can i compress this output and remove whitespaces from json array which you create ?

Comment: change JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2); to JSON.stringify(arr);